# PHP regular expression get float value between brackets

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a little problem with getting some numbers from a string.

For example I have this kind of str:

```
qweqeqe (qweqwe) AASD 213,21 ( -1201,77 EUR )
```

I need the numbers with comma that are between brackets
Result: `-1201,77`
The value also can be positive.
I have already managed to get float value, but from all string.
I have this: `!\d+(?:\,\d+)?!` but it gets all numbers in a str.

Comment: Try `.*\(\s*(-?[\d,]+)[\w\s]*\)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this pattern :

```
$pattern = "#\([\s]*(-{0,1}[0-9]+,[0-9]+)[\s]*[A-Za-z]*[\s]*\)#";
```

Answer (score 2):

**IF THERE IS ALWAYS 1 NUMBER INSIDE PARENTHESES...**

Here is a two-pass, "readable" approach: extract all parenthetical substrings and then use `preg_filter` to extract the float values:

```
$s = "qweqeqe (qweqwe) AASD 213,21 ( -1201,77 EUR )";
preg_match_all('/\([^()]*\)/', $s, $parentheses);
$res = preg_filter('/.*?([+-]?\d+(?:,\d+)?).*/s', '$1', $parentheses[0]);
                     ^^^     ^
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/3qvGhw)

Here, we match any symbols before and after float with `.*`. Note that to preserve the number, we need to use lazy dot matching in the left part (`.*?`), and we can match anything in the part after the number. As the `+`/`-` before the number are optional, use a `?` quantifier: `[-+]?`.

**IF THERE CAN BE MORE THAN 1 NUMBER INSIDE PARENTHESES...**

It is a less readable one-pass approach:

```
$s = "qweqeqe (qweqwe) AASD 213,21 ( -1201,77 EUR )";
preg_match_all('/(?:\(|(?!^)\G)[^()]*?([+-]?\d+(?:,\d+)?)(?=[^()]*\))/', $s, $matches);
                                       ^^^^
```

See [another IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/1STlKN)

Here, the regex defines the starting boundary with `(?:\(|(?!^)\G)` (that is, start looking for the numbers after `(` and then after each successful match) and then capture the floats with `[^()]*?(\d+(?:,\d+)?)` but ensuring we are still inside the parentheses (the rightmost boundary is checked with the `(?=[^()]*\))` lookahead).

Comment: Should your main capture group in the second example be ([+-]?\d+(?:,\d+) to account for negatives?

Comment: Sorry, was in a hurry. Fixed both.